# EWSのNotificationEvent(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemEvent）を使ってのメール取得が失敗します。

Tags: c#, .net

以下のソースのように、NotificationEventのitemIDからメールを取得するソースを動かしていました。

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemEvent itemEV = (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemEvent)e;
Item item = Item.Bind(ewsClient, itemEV.ItemId);
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage emailData = (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage)item;
```

近日になって、Item.Bindの箇所でエラーとなり、以下のメッセージがでています。

> The EWS Id is in EwsLegacyId format which is not supported by the
> Exchange version specified by your request. Please use the ConvertId
> method to convert from EwsLegacyId to EwsId format.

NotificationEventのitemIDを変換する必要があるように見えますが、回避策を教えて頂きたく、お願いします。
（EWSのIDフォーマットを変える必要があるように見受けられますが、EWSから首都kした値を変更するのもちょっとおかしいと思い、ご質問させていただきました。）

Answer (score 3):

英語版の[stackoverflowで回答を頂き](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77652287/11932445)、解決したので、こちらにも自己回答しておきます。
以下のソースで解決しました。

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemEvent itemEV = (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemEvent)e;

AlternateId inputId = new AlternateId
{
    Format = IdFormat.EwsLegacyId,
    Mailbox = "mailaddress",
    UniqueId = itemEV.ItemId.UniqueId
};
AlternateId alternateId = (AlternateId)ewsClient.ConvertId(inputId, IdFormat.EwsId);
ItemId convertitemId = new ItemId(alternateId.UniqueId);

Item item = Item.Bind(ewsClient, convertitemId);
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage emailData = (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage)item;
```